# drupal_http_request returns error code

Tags: php, sockets, drupal, curl, drupal-hooks

I have three website Main ,a, b. If you logged in through "Main" website then i will enable  session for websites "a", "b". So this is working fine. When user logged out of Main Website, i have to loggout of other two website "a", "b". There are two different logout url for the other two website so i am calling those two website's logout url in the Main website's logout function using drupal_http_request

Example CODE:

```
// this is the function where main website session are destroyed
function mymodule_logout(){ 

session_destory(); 

$request =  drupal_http_request("http://B-website.com:8083/VideoBook/signout.action");

print_r($request); 

if($request) { 
drupal_goto($logout_url,$options); 
}


}
```

OUTPUT :

```
stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 
[error] => Error opening socket ssl://mywebsite.com:8443 
[redirect_code] => 302 
[redirect_url] => https://mywebsite.com:8443/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite2.com%3A8083%2FVideoBook%2Flogin.action )
```

B-website-logout-url : http://B-website.com:8083/VideoBook/signout.action

When i run this logout url  in the browser tab , then all the session and cookies are destroyed , But when i run this logout url using drupal_http_request('http://B-website.com:8083/VideoBook/signout.action'); , then it results in error "Error Opening Socket ssl:// " .  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: with curl found couldn't connect to host error check your hostconnection

Comment: Rahesh Sharma. thanks for your response

Comment: I can't understand. Can you explain it briefly?

Comment: I also facing the same issue, if someone have any solution of this please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the signout.action requires session data i.e currently logged in user details but we are not able to send the session data through the curl. so its redirecting to the login.action. So it results in error code 302.