# Single logout for multiple website

Tags: php, session, drupal, cookies, multiple-domains

I'm working in a drupal website. I have three websites. Main website, Website A, Website B. My requirement is that Once the user logout of the Main Website, then user should be logout of other two websites ( Website A, Website B) .

Solution 1:

I have search a lot but i cant find a solution.  I'm thinking to clear cookies and session of other two websites ( Website A, B) once user logout of Main website. But i can't find code to delete cookies and session of the Multiple different domains ( WebsiteA.com, WebsiteB.com ) .

Solution 2 :

I have raised another question ( [drupal_http_request returns error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670926/drupal-http-request-returns-error-code) ) which i explained clearly about my solution 2. But there also i'm getting struct.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to have an encrypted session(SHA + SALT key) with a same ID across all sites. When your reaching another domain,sub-domain you then check if the session is set and if it is, log the user otherwise do nothing. If the user logout from one site, kill the session.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
save session in Database. 
from Website A, Website B you can check if the session from the Main website exists, if not log out.

The Simple way in a Main website create code that in a case no session['logined'] call the logout pages on Website A, Website by curl